# Wordpress: вызвать редактор custom post type в frontend

Tags: wordpress

Можно ли вызвать редактор определенного типа записей в плагине / на странице frontend?

Comment: Можно. Разрешаю :) В чем проблема-то? Нужны подобности, желательно с учестками кода, который не работает

Comment: хотя-бы тыкните носом в документацию, где читать. Мне нужно вызвать сам редактор со всеми мета-полями.  Я даже не знаю, как его во фронтенде вызвать. В админке редактирование работает нормально

Comment: Вот скрин - http://i.imgur.com/039JDCx.jpg

Comment: или может при регистрации типа записей нужно указывать параметры паблик?

Comment: Я подумал, что вы про редактор WISIWIG. Если вам надо именно вот как на скрине, то даже не знаю. Я достаточно опытен в WP, но мне кажется прямо вот в пару строк решения не будет. Придется писать очень много велосипедов.

Comment: Если быть более точным, то для фронта придется писать свой интерфейс. Серверную часть получится использовать ту же самую, только, наверное, несколько хуков добавить. И то, что вам нужно, будет не в документации, а в исходниках.

Comment: я так и подумал, что для этого придется создавать темплейт редактора, выводить все поля и передавать в функцию wp_update_post()....Чтож, спасибо за ответ